# How To Use SharedPreferences With LatLng (Errors)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am facing a problem implamenting LatLng with SharePrefrences.I am getting an error that I have no way how to fix and I will be glad for some help.

This are my codes:

```
protected boolean saveCordArray() {
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME2, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = sp.edit();
    Set<LatLng> set = new HashSet<LatLng>();
    set.addAll(MainActivity.mPlacesCord);
    mEdit1.putStringSet("cords", latLngFinal);
    Log.e("saveCordArray!", String.valueOf(latLngFinal) + address);
    return mEdit1.commit();
}


public ArrayList<String> getArray() {

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME2, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> set = sp.getStringSet("cords", new HashSet<String>());
    return new ArrayList<String>(set);
}
```

And photos of the errors:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

If I can't use LatLng with SharedPreferences what is the best alternative?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you pls post code of your latLngFinal?

Answer (score 0):

putStringSet will only save Set a set of String values in the preferences editor, you cannot set of LatLng with this.

You can use Gson to serialise the set to json string and store the json in the preferences, and retrieve.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(;;your data set;;);

editor.putString(TAG, json);
editor.commit();
```

Retrievenig :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TAG, "");
Type type = new TypeToken<Set<CUSTOMOBJECT>>() {}.getType();
Set<CUSTOMOBJECT> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: Hey,Thank you very much for your replay!

When I call the retrievenig function,its crash my app with the following error:

"Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2"

Here is a photo:
https://ibb.co/HP8c0YG

and this is the code I implemented:
https://ibb.co/mt6T4x1

I couldn't change the "arraylist" inside the square to my arraylist..